# Using Multithreading for same Form instance?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a single-threaded C# tool in which there are a bunch of UI input controls. Based on these controls, and some input Excel files, some processing is being done. This processing takes 10~15 seconds during which the program is non-responsive. After the work is done, the output text is mentioned in a text box.

Now I have a function which does all the work. However, this function is dependent on the UI inputs the user provided.

I just tried applying some threading using this code:

```
workerThread = new Thread(this.WorkerFunction);
workerThread.Start();
//workerThread.Join();
output.Text = outputStringBuilder.ToString();
```

I'm basically using the same Form instance here, because using another Form instance won't work because that new Form instance won't contain the user specified inputs.

As the code is mentioned above, it does *not* work. I don't see the output text in the text box. It only works if I enable the `workerThread.Join();` statement, but then I see experience the 10~15 second lag, which breaks the whole point of threading ..

So how can I add threading to this setup, without having to add a whole bunch of input parameters to the workerFunction (as I want to see the UI control inputs as it is) .. ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Because `output.Text = outputStringBuilder.ToString();` is being executed immediately, before `this.WorkerFunction` is finished.

Comment: Don't use (bare) threads, look at ThreadPool, Backgroundworker and TPL. In this case probably Backgroundworker.

Comment: Look into refactoring this part of the code to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> However, this function is dependent on the UI inputs the user provided.

Well, that's the first issue that you need to address.  You need to separate out your UI interactions from your business logic and long running processes.

*Before* you call your long running function you should extract whatever information from your UI that is needed to do this processing.  Pass that information to the method that does the processing via one or more parameters.  If there is a lot of information it may be worth encapsulating in a specific data holder class (or classes, or collections, etc., depending on the extent of the information).

Next, rather than having this process update the UI with whatever results it generates have this function return a value representing the results of the business operation; the UI code can then take those results and manipulate the UI as needed.

Now, there are a number of different threading tools specifically designed to aid you in the task of performing a long running operation in a UI program while doing the long running work in another thread but while performing UI related work in the UI context.  One of these is the `BackgroundWorker` class.  (If you're using C# 5.0 you can use the Task Parallel Library in conjunction with the `async` and `await` keywords, which is honestly much better.)

Once you've done this your code will fit nicely into the functionality provided by `BackroundWorker`.

Start out by pulling out the data from the UI.  Then create the BGW, assign a `DoWork` handler to do the work and use the information you pulled from the UI.  Set the `Result` to the results of the operation.  Then use the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler to update the UI with those results.

```
var myUIInfo = new SomeClass(){Info = someControl.Text
    , Other = someOtherControl.Selected};
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (s,e) => e.Result = LongRunningProcess(myUIInfo);
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) += UpdateUIWith(e.Result);
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your task is simple and takes just a few lines of code, then instead of the whole BackgroundWorker setup, you could simply move the output.Text update to the WorkerFunction. Remember to use the Dispatcher otherwise it won't work, here's how:

```
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
            delegate
            {
                // Update output.Text here
            }
            ));
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be encouraging people to intermingle their business logic and UI interaction.

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the task. If the task is very simple, there is no point in separating logic because you'll get more headache in setting up the plumbing than actually using it. If its a simple task then the solution to this should be respectively simple. I guess it depends on the complexity. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It literally takes 5-10 *seconds* to create what you need to use a `BackgroundWorker`.  It'll take about as long as it will to write out even 2 `Invoke` calls.  You're not saving time doing that; you're just making your program harder to read, maintain, reason about, etc. for at best a few seconds of your time.